# Need to email multiple recipients from combobox

Tags: php

I need to email multiple email addresses from each selection of a drop down box, however everything i have tried is not working..  Here is what I have so far

Im using this in the start of the form

```
 $mailto = $_POST['unit'];
```

This is what I have for the drop down box

```
<select name="unit" size="1" id="Combobox1"     style="position:absolute;left:43px;top:324px;width:61px;height:21px;z-      index:18;">
 <option value= 'email@email.com'; 'email@email.com'> M17</option>
 <option value="email@email.com">M16</option>
 </select>
```

The problems im having
1. on option M17 it only sends to the first email address
2. it sends the email address instead of the unit number (M17)
3. Need to figure out a way to edit the email addresses through a seperate "user friendly" page

```
</head>
<body>
<div id="space"><br></div>
<div id="container">
<div id="wb_Form1"             
<form name="11_Dispatch" method="post" action="<?php echo basename(__FILE__); ?>" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="Form1">
<input type="hidden" name="formid" value="form1">
<div id="wb_Text1" style="position:absolute;left:10px;top:76px;width:111px;height:16px;z-index:0;text-align:left;">
<span style="color:#000000;font-family:Arial;font-size:13px;">Address</span>    </div>
<input type="text" id="Editbox1" style="position:absolute;left:131px;top:76px;width:198px;height:23px;line-height:23px;z-index:1;" name="LOC" value="">
<div id="wb_Text2" style="position:absolute;left:10px;top:106px;width:111px;height:16px;z-index:2;text-align:left;">
 <span style="color:#000000;font-family:Arial;font-size:13px;">Subdivision</span></div>
 <input type="text" id="Editbox2" style="position:absolute;left:131px;top:106px;width:198px;height:23px;line-height:23px;z-index:3;" name="SUB" value="">
<div id="wb_Text3" style="position:absolute;left:10px;top:136px;width:111px;height:16px;z-index:4;text-align:left;">
<span style="color:#000000;font-family:Arial;font-size:13px;">Call back #     </span></div>
<input type="text" id="Editbox3" style="position:absolute;left:131px;top:136px;width:198px;height:23px;line-height:23px;z-index:5;" name="#" value="">
<div id="wb_Text5" style="position:absolute;left:10px;top:166px;width:111px;height:16px;z-index:6;text-align:left;">
<span style="color:#000000;font-family:Arial;font-size:13px;">Chief Complaint</span></div>
<input type="text" id="Editbox4" style="position:absolute;left:131px;top:166px;width:198px;height:23px;line-height:23px;z-index:7;" name="CC" value="">
<div id="wb_Text6" style="position:absolute;left:10px;top:196px;width:111px;height:16px;z-index:8;text-align:left;">
<span style="color:#000000;font-family:Arial;font-size:13px;">Pt name</span>    </div>
<input type="text" id="Editbox5" style="position:absolute;left:131px;top:196px;width:198px;height:23px;line-height:23px;z-index:9;" name="NAME" value="">
<div id="wb_Text7" style="position:absolute;left:10px;top:226px;width:111px;height:16px;z-index:10;text-align:left;">
 <span style="color:#000000;font-family:Arial;font-size:13px;">Pt Age</span>  </div>
 <input type="text" id="Editbox6" style="position:absolute;left:131px;top:226px;width:198px;height:23px;line-height:23px;z-index:11;" name="AGE" value="">
 <div id="wb_Text9" style="position:absolute;left:10px;top:256px;width:111px;height:16px;z-index:12;text-align:left;">
 <span style="color:#000000;font-family:Arial;font-size:13px;">Callers Name</span></div>
 <input type="text" id="Editbox7" style="position:absolute;left:131px;top:256px;width:198px;height:23px;line-height:23px;z-index:13;" name="CALLER" value="">
 <div id="wb_Text10" style="position:absolute;left:10px;top:286px;width:111px;height:16px;z-index:14;text-align:left;">
 <span style="color:#000000;font-family:Arial;font-size:13px;">Identifying Factors</span></div>
 <input type="text" id="Editbox8" style="position:absolute;left:131px;top:286px;width:198px;height:23px;line-height:23px;z-index:15;" name="NOTES" value="">
 <input type="submit" id="Button2" name="" value="Dispatch" style="position:absolute;left:169px;top:357px;width:96px;height:25px;z-index:16;">
 <div id="wb_Text12" style="position:absolute;left:166px;top:30px;width:133px;height:22px;z-index:17;text-align:left;">
 <span style="color:#000000;font-family:Arial;font-size:19px;"><strong>911 Dispatch</strong></span></div>
 <select name="unit" size="1" id="Combobox1" style="position:absolute;left:43px;top:324px;width:61px;height:21px;z-index:18;">
<option value="M17">M17 </option>
<option value="M16">M16</option>
<option value="M15">M15</option>
<option value="M14">M14</option>
<option value="M11">M11</option>
<option value="M10">M10</option>
<option value="M07">M07</option>
</select>
</form>
```

Comment: Drop the email addresses from your select and use an array in your PHP instead; just make them choose M17, and use `isset()`. You also shouldn't be showing others what the email addresses are, they're bound to get spammed.

Comment: Fred i have searched google for it ....I cant find anything that works....I swear I have tried everything....except an array, simply because i have no experiance with an array and have no clue where to start.  Any Pointers?  thanks for your help in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested, don't put your `to` addresses in the form. This is just basic and the `mail()` part is right from the manual -> http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php  (**Example #4 Sending HTML email** shows multiple email recipients using concatenation however, I am using implosion):

**PHP:**

```
if(isset($_POST['unit'])) {
    // Store emails in the code or database to draw from:
    // Personally I like to store this in an array (if I were to hardcode it)
    // Reason being, is that if you suddenly one day get access to a database
    // and you draw a bunch of email addresses from that database, those emails
    // would likely be listed as an array.

    // By storing each email in a same-named array, you basically
    // create an easy-to-read mailing list
    $units['m17'][] = 'email1@tester.com';
    $units['m17'][] = 'email2@tester.com';
    $units['m16'][] = 'email3@tester.com';

    // if the <select> value of $_POST['unit'] equals 'm17'
    // $units[$_POST['unit']] then is the same as $units['m17']
    $to       =  implode(",",$units[$_POST['unit']]);
    $subject  =  'the subject';
    $message  =  'hello';
    $headers  =  'From: webmaster@example.com'."\r\n";

    // As noted in the PHP Manual, the function implode() takes an array
    // and combines the values into a string with a "glue", in this case a comma
    // $to would then equal: "email1@tester.com,email2@tester.com" if
    // $_POST['unit'] equals 'm17'.
    mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
}
```

**FORM:**

```
<select name="unit" size="1" id="Combobox1" style="position: absolute; left: 43px; top: 324px; width: 61px; height: 21px; z-index: 18;">
    <option value="m17">M17</option>
    <option value="m16">M16</option>
</select>
```

Comment: that works great!  one problem, how do i get my form to be the message?  it did it before but after i added your code it no longer sends it as the message?

Comment: I don't know what you had for a message. You would assign `$message` your form information. Right now `$message = 'hello';` in my example

Comment: should just be the form name right?  or does it need []

Comment: What are you trying to send as the message, the data from the form? I'm not sure what what you are trying to send, you didn't post that portion of your code.

Comment: yes I am trying to send the data from the form.  I will post what I have in just a moment

Comment: You could probably just loop through the `$_POST` data and echo the `$keys` and `$values`

Comment: Thank you very much for your help.  I think i got it from here.   thanks again!

Comment: No problem! Make sure you mark the answer correct so people don't keep coming to try and solve the issue.